# Convert oracle Sql to postgresql with "CONNECT BY level"

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, datetime, recursive-query

as "CONNECT BY level" keywords is not supported on PostgreSQL i couldn't translate below sql to  PostgreSQL

Please advise how can I rewrite below oracle SQL on PostgreSQL :

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('01/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') + level - 1 AS days,
    level AS level1
FROM
    dual
CONNECT BY
    level <= (
        SELECT
            abs(TO_DATE('01/01/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/10/2021','MM/DD/YYYY') )
        FROM
            dual
        WHERE
            'Daily' = 'Daily'
    )
```

result :

```
01-JAN-19   1
02-JAN-19   2
03-JAN-19   3
04-JAN-19   4
05-JAN-19   5
06-JAN-19   6
07-JAN-19   7
08-JAN-19   8
09-JAN-19   9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a handy function called [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), which makes this kind of task easy:

```
select dt::date, rn
from generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2019-01-09'::date, '1 day') 
    with ordinality as d(dt, rn)
```

I don't see the point for the obsfucated logic in the `connect by` clause of the Oracle query; the scalar subquery always evaluates as `9`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=88ef0e7864e41cab6d7f6b8530ebee48)**:

```
dt         | rn
:--------- | -:
2019-01-01 |  1
2019-01-02 |  2
2019-01-03 |  3
2019-01-04 |  4
2019-01-05 |  5
2019-01-06 |  6
2019-01-07 |  7
2019-01-08 |  8
2019-01-09 |  9
```

Comment: Agreed the Oracle is obscure, but lets not think it is Oracle's doing, but the author. The Oracle could have been "select date '2019-01-01' + level - 1 days, level rn from dual connect by level <= 9;" Just as the Postgres version could have been the almost identical "select date '2019-01-01' + level - 1, level rn from generate_series(1,9) gn(level);" I do prefer your query but point is do not blame Oracle because the author writes poor sql.

Comment: @Belayer: sure. My comment was not referring to Oracle, but to the logic of the query itself (as written by its original author).